# JavaScript - Infinite State Loop - Pan Function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, delta

In my free time I am currently reading the book "Pro HTML5 Games" written by Aditya Ravi Shankar.

At the moment I am struggling with understanding the following line of code:

```
var deltaX = Math.round((newCenter - game.offsetLeft - game.canvas.width / 4)/ 2);
```

Can anyone tell me what's the reason for the following part? ( ... `- game.canvas.width / 4) / 2)`

In one loop this formula resolves too `270 = Math.round((700 - 0 - 640 / 4) / 2)` for the value of `deltaX`. Can anyone see the correlation of this value to the game?

Eventuell the following line of code gets called:

```
 deltaX = game.maxSpeed * Math.abs(deltaX) / (deltaX);
```

Which corresponds to:

```
3 = 3 * Math.abs(270) / (270);
```

Appartently, deltaX just matters for the sake of right / left panning.

So where does this delta value for `deltaX` belong too?

Here are some additional values that might be helpful (x-axis):

**game canvas:** 640px

**background picture:** 1024px

The code for the whole project can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/davidg0/8531c336068adf9f4b26):

Answer (score 1):

Typically in mathematics, delta refers to the change in something over a period of time. In this instance your `deltax` variable is simply being used to calculate the change in `x` needed to move to the desired pan location (in this case that location is `newCenter`).

If your goal is to understand the exact application of the mathematics then I'd suggest trying your luck over at one of SO's [math sister sites](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Valid point - I might give it a shot over there. I was a bit worried, they might not have the necessary programming background to answer the question.